# Reconnection failed : paho mqtt using javascript

Tags: react-native, mqtt, iot, paho

When the connection is lost, the function onConnectionLost will be called, but how do I reconnect when the connection is lost?

here is my code :

```
     const client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(host, Number(port), clientID);
    client.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived;
    client.onConnectionLost = this.onConnectionLost;
    client.connect({ 
           cleanSession : false, 
                onSuccess : this.onConnect, 
                userName: "user",
                password: "pass",
                onFailure : this.onConnectionLost, 
                keepAliveInterval: 30, 
                reconnect : true,         // Enable automatic reconnect
                reconnectInterval: 10     // Reconnect attempt interval : 10 seconds
    });
onConnect = () => {
    const { client } = this.state;
    console.log("Connected!!!!");
    this.setState({isConnected: true, error: ''});
    client.subscribe(topic, qos=1);
    client.subscribe(topic1, qos=1);
    client.subscribe(topic2, qos=1);
  };

  onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
    if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
      console.log("onConnectionLost : "+responseObject.errorMessage);
      this.setState({error: 'Lost Connection', isConnected: false});
    }
  }
```

> Error: Unknown property, reconnectInterval. Valid properties are:
> timeout userName password willMessage keepAliveInterval cleanSession
> useSSL invocationContext onSuccess onFailure hosts ports reconnect
> mqttVersion mqttVersionExplicit uris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the reconnect parameter

```
client.connect(
            {
                cleanSession : false, 
                onSuccess : onConnectSuccess, 
                onFailure : onFailedConnect, 
                keepAliveInterval: 30, 
                reconnect : true,         // Enable automatic reconnect
            }
```

https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/jsdoc/Paho.MQTT.Client.html

Comment: I tried to add those option but it return this Error: Unknown property, reconnectInterval. Valid properties are: timeout userName password willMessage keepAliveInterval cleanSession useSSL invocationContext onSuccess onFailure hosts ports reconnect mqttVersion mqttVersionExplicit uris

Comment: Alright. This error says that the property 'reconnectInteval' is unknown. It also says that all the other properties you used are correct. So just remove 'reconnectInterval'. I'll edit the answer too

Comment: Now thats working but after a few seconds it reconnect auto and I have many pages each page subscribe two topic

Comment: Glad to know that it worked!! Please, if this other bug still persists, create a new question so everybody can help and learn as well. Best regards!